# How do I create a UiWidget at runtime as an entity?

Tags: user-interface, rust, amethyst

Imagine I've created a container

```rust
let created = UiWidget::Container::<NoCustomUi, String, ()> {
    transform: UiTransformData::default(),
    background: None,
    children: Vec::new(),
};
```

How do I add it to the world and get its entity back? Something like:

```rust
let entity = world
    .create_entity()
    .with(container)
    .build();
```

But it says "the trait `specs::world::comp::Component` is not implemented for `amethyst_ui::prefab::UiWidget<amethyst_ui::prefab::NoCustomUi, std::string::String>`".

I'm using Amethyst v0.15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UiWidget` actually can't be added to an `Entity` directly, as it's meant to be loaded through the `Prefab`

You have to create [`UiTransform`](https://docs.amethyst.rs/stable/amethyst_ui/struct.UiTransform.html), [`UiText`](https://docs.amethyst.rs/stable/amethyst_ui/struct.UiText.html) or one of the few other `Struct` from `amethyst::ui` that implements `Component` and add them to an `Entity`

```rust
let ui_transform = UiTransform::new(
    String::from("demo_text"),   // id
    Anchor::Middle,              // anchor
    Anchor::Middle,              // pivot
    0f32,                        // x
    0f32,                        // y
    0f32,                        // z
    100f32,                      // width
    30f32,                       // height
);

let ui_text = UiText::new(
    font_handle,                 // font
    String::from("Hello World"), // text
    [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.5],        // color
    25f32,                       // font_size
    LineMode::Single,            // line mode
    Anchor::Middle,              // alignment
);

world.create_entity()
    .with(ui_transform)
    .with(ui_text)
    .build();
```

You can find more information on how to do that in the Amethyst book under the [User Interface section](https://book.amethyst.rs/stable/ui/introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the book has been updated few days ago.